# yii1 how to get userdata from Yii::app()->user command

Tags: php, yii

I want to get the role id of the logged user to make visible specific links of website. currently I have student and tutor tables and separate login for both users. student table has role as 1 and tutor table as role as 2, how can I check the logged user's role .

I tried

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->role;?>
```

but it returns following error

```
Property "CWebUser.role" is not defined.
```

pls advice

Comment: What about `Yii::app()->user->getState('role')`?

Comment: @raina77ow : it return nothing..

Comment: helpful: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6489-change-layout-depending-on-user-role/page__p__33314#entry33314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Using `setState()` in extended `CUserIdentity` class. It calls once during user auth and woudn't be updated on next page refresh. Don't store there important information like roles or passwords, cause it could be stored in cookie. It easy to store there information like name, last visit time, etc.

Here is an example: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user

2. Extends `CWebUser` and add some public methods, for example `getRole()`:

**main.php**

```
'user' => array('class' => 'application.components.WebUser')
```

**WebUser.php**

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    public $role;

    public function getRole(){
        if ($this->role === null) {
            // Here you need to get User role
            $this->role = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT role FROM {{user}} WHERE id=:id")->queryScalar(array(':id' => Yii::app()->user->id));
        }

        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

Then call if where you need `Yii::app()->user->role` or `Yii::app()->user->getRole()`